# semantic search that finds sentences that could be expressed visually

Tags: machine-learning, search-engine, information-retrieval

Let's say I want to build a search engine that goes through a text and finds sentences or paragraphs that could be turned into an image, video or 3d-animation. So sentences that contain information that could be expressed visually.
Ideally, this search engine would get better over time.

1. Is there already search engine that could to that?
2. If not, which type of things would I need to look at/consider? My point here being that I don't really know much about machine learning and search engines. I am trying to get a feeling of which areas of machine learning, information retrieval and so forth I would need to look at.

I don't expect long answers here, just things like "well, take a look at this type of machine learning" or "this part of information retrieval theory may be relevant".

Just to get a broad overview of what I would need to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Natural Language Understanding**

I don't know about any existing search engine doing that. But this can be done with the help of **Natural Language Understanding** and **Semantic Parsing**.

Have a look at Stanford's Natural Language Understanding [course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224u/) (discussion of the *text-to-scene* problem can be found [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224u/materials/cs224u-2015-text2scene.pdf)) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

How [semantic search](http://www.kamkash.com/seo-semantic-search-expert-david-amerland-interview/) works is, it analysis data and put them into a 3-D vector space. One it's done with the help of bid data and knowledge graph the algorithm will try to find data points that connect to the article, the authority of the author, website relevance, and a couple of other factors. Once these factors are factored in, it then tries to create co-relate data to create a layer of information interconnected to each other. Once these information's are gathered then it is used to arrive at a conclusion to decide how relevant the data is.